Linux ubuntu. Проблема с входом и граф.средой
Я пытался установить waeusb, чтобы записать образ винды, но никак не получалось установить через терминал. Было много ошибок (я буквально новичок в линуксе).
Решил спросить у ChatGPT, что делать. Он посоветовал удалить пакет libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common, который вызвал ошибку. Я попробовал это решение и экран погас.
Я пишу ChatGPT, почему экран погас. Он мне даёт советы, как все восстановить. Кое как я смог восстановить этот пакет, но при запуске ПК графическая среда так и не появилась, только консоль. Спрашиваю его, что делать. В итоге смог восстановить граф. среду. Когда появляется экран входа, его интерфейс выглядит по-другому, и я не могу войти. Когда пытаюсь ввести пароль, компьютер пишет 'не начало сессии', пароль верный. Ещё пробовал через консоль.
Нажал ctrl+alt+f1, но там он пишет, что логин неверный, но на самом деле он правильный.
Знаю, звучит смешно, но прошу искренней помощи.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Ctrl+Alt+7 - выдаёт гуй?

Совет удалить libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common примерно равнозначен совету "если у вас болит нога, просто отрубите её". Если вы уже раздолбали систему, то наверно проще будет просто переустановить её

Или если это обычная убунта, то, может, установка пакета ubuntu-desktop сможет вернуть всё примерно как было (или kubuntu-desktop для кубунты и по аналогии для других версий убунты)

Совет, не надо спрашивать у чата что либо, и тут же делать... Что он предложит

Да, это я понял когда говна наворотил, просто хотел получить быстрый ответ на решение. Я не думал, что гпт может посоветовать удалить такой важный пакет. То что написал человек выше про ubuntu-desktop, точно не помню но как будто уже это делал и были ошибки с какими-то ссылками

Возможно, проблема в неправильном менеджере дисплеев. Чтобы вернуть все как было, нужно перенастроить любой пакет менеджера дисплеев с помощью sudo dpkg-reconfigure <имя менеджера дисплеев>. Имя может быть gdm, sddm, lightdm. Если не помогает, удалите пакет ubuntu-desktop вместе с зависимостями и установите снова.
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

Чтобы попасть в консоль:

Выключите компьютер
Включите его снова и сразу после исчезновения логотипа нажимайте Esc.
Если появится командная строка, пишите normal и жмите Esc снова.
Выберите вашу ОС из списка и нажмите e.
Добавьте в конец параметров ядра 3.
Нажмите Ctrl+X.
Система должна загрузится в командную строку.

Если и это не поможет, пишите в комменты, и я дополню ответ. В крайнем случае сделайте бэкап важных данных и переустановите систему.

Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. dpkg-reconfigure не помогло. Удалить ubuntu-desktop вроде получилось, а вот установить нет , ошибка такая: Error, pkgProblemResolver :: Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. В консоль зашёл через шифт, recovery mode.

Попробуйте sudo apt —fix-broken install ubuntu-desktop. Если не поможет, боюсь, что придется переустановить ОС.

Спасибо большое, что пытались помочь. Было действительно проще переустановить линукс, что я и сделал, но возникли другие проблемы из того, что хочу установить винду, расписывать конечно тут не буду и еще раз спасибо за помощь.
